# How do I creating a table with stored procedure results on Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

[image]

Im trying to schedule my stored procedure to run every day and save the results into a table.
I got the stored procedure to work but im not able to create a table with the results.

Creating a table backed by the SP to run daily

Answer (score 0):

You can use DDL statements where you're executing queries in your stored procedure, before the SQL of your output query.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `datasetId.tableId`
```

[CREATE TABLE statement](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#create_table_statement)

Answer (score 0):

Whatever your result query is: try to use DDL of create/replace table to save the results.

something like :

```
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE CONCAT("create or replace table `",YOUR_TABLE_NAME_VARIABLE,"` as YOUR_QUERY_HERE");
EXCEPTION WHEN ERROR THEN
    RAISE USING MESSAGE = CONCAT('StoredProc Error: ',@@error.message);
END;
```

Comment: Hello @pratik, I tried going your route but seems like i get this error. "Syntax error: Expected ")" but got keyword CREATE"

Comment: BEGIN EXECUTE IMMEDIATE CONCAT(create or replace table,"database_folder_table" as "query");EXCEPTION WHEN ERROR THEN
    RAISE USING MESSAGE = CONCAT('StoredProc Error: ',@@error.message);
END;

Comment: this concat syntax needs correct placement of double quotes, what I shared is just a template, you will need to replace correct things in it. In your second comment I see you removed double quotes from the start of create, that is not going to work. Think of it as gigantic string concat. To check the correctness you can just try a simple query like "create or replace table `somename` as select 1" inside concat function first and then work towards adding parameterized variables if needs to.